# How to reshape an array to 3d using keras

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, keras, data-science

I have 1260 rows and 2 columns that represent a feature per column (i.e. 'Open','High') for stock predictions. I need to reshape this array into the 3D array for input into Nerual Network using LSTM.

This is my code so far:

```
X_train, y_train = np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train)
X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 2))
```

The last line of the code I am confused about what it is telling me. It's meant to put it into a 3D array but it seems like a 2D array to me.

How can I feed the network an array (or vector of Open values) and an array of High Values.

Comment: What's your window size? i.e. timesteps?

Answer (score 0):

I assume `X_train.shape` is a 2D tensor, if you want to make it 3D you can use [np.expand_dims](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html)

Example

```
arr = np.random.randint(0,5,(3,3))

array([[3, 4, 1],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [4, 4, 2]])

arr.shape = (3,3)
```

```
reshape_arr = np.np.expand_dims(arr, -1)
reshape_arr.shape = (3,3,1)
```